# implementing a background process responding to the client in an atmosphere+netty/jetty application

Tags: asynchronous, websocket, jetty, netty, atmosphere

We have a requirement to to support **10k+** users, where every user initiate a request and waits for a response from the server (the response can take as long as 20-30 seconds to arrive). it is only one request from the client, and after a long processing by the server, a response will be transmitted and then the connection will disconnect.
in the background, the server will do some DB search and wait for other background processes to notify on completion before responding to the client.

after doing some research i figured out we will need to use something like the **atmosphere** framework to support websockets/sse event/long polling along with an asynchronous server like **netty** (=> **nettosphere**) or **jetty**. 
As for my experience - mostly Java EE world and Tomcat server.

my questions are:

1. what will be easier to implement in regard to my experience and our requirement: atmosphere + netty or atmoshphere+jetty? which one can scale better, has an easier learning curve and easier to implement other java technologies?
2. how do u implement in atmosphere a response that is sent only to the originating client and not broadcast to the rest of the clients? (all the examples i found are broadcast).
3. how can i implement in netty (or jetty) when using the atmosphere framework our response? i.e., the client send a request, after it is received in the server some background processes are run, and when they finish i need to locate the connection and transmit the response. is that achievable?

Comment: Look into [cometd](http://cometd.org/) too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some thoughts:

1. At 10k+ users, with 20-30 second response latency, you likely hit file descriptor limits if using just 1 network interface.  Consider a solution that uses multiple network interfaces.
2. Your description of your request/response can be handled entirely with standard Servlet 3.0, standard HTTP/1.1, Async request handling, and large timeouts.
3. If your clients are web browsers, and you don't start sending a response from the server until the 20-30 second window, you might hit browser idle timeouts.
4. Atmosphere and Cometd do the same things, supporting long duration connections, with connection technique fallbacks, and with logical channel APIs.

Comment: as regarding your #3+#4 comments- i thought we need atmosphere to handle the connections.
As regarding #2- wouldn't i need to spawn a lot of threads to handle the requests? or can i just keep asyncServlet in a cache and access it when the background process access the server?

Comment: Your concerns about the threads are misplaced, threads are only alive and allocated based on actual active processing. Said another way ... Thread count != Connection count when Servlet 3.0 Async is in the mix.

Comment: Know that with Atomosphere and Cometd, the long duration request/response is handled with alternate connection types (http streaming, http long polling, websocket, etc).  If on a web browser, responses from these types of connections will then have to be processed by yourself, in javascript, to then be displayed how you want in the browser.

Comment: It would probably help you to read up on the Bayeux Protocol, BOSH, and the like.  You will quickly learn that all of these techniques will use more than 1 connection over the life of the request/response  (with various javascript side management) in order to accomplish their goals.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the AKKA framework will handle this sort of need. I am looking at using it to handle scaling issues possibly with a RabbitMQ to help off load work to potentially other servers that may be added later to scale as needed.